# Why is the Django template file not updating value from the context?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

(I am a beginner in Django)

I am following along a tutorial in Django where we can dynamically pass some variable to a template file from associated function in views.py

When I am running the code for the first time, it works fine, but when I change the values within the context, the template does not update with the new values even when I refresh it

Here is my views.py code -

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    
    # Create your views here.
    def index(request):
        # return HttpResponse('<h1>Hey, welcome</h1>')
        # we can dynamically send data to our index.html file as follows -
        context={
            'u_name': 'Ankit',
            'u_age': 25,
            'u_nationality': 'Indian',
        }
        return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

Here is my template index.html -

```
<h1>
    How are you doing today {{u_name}} <br>You are {{u_age}} years old<br>Your nationality is {{u_nationality}}
</h1>
```

settings.py has been correctly set as well -

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,'templates'],
```

Editing post to add urls.py as well (this is within the app)

```
from . import views
from django.urls import include,path

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index')
]
```

And the urls.py in the main project -

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('MyApp.urls'))
]
```

Here is my output -
[does not take the values from the context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXQhn.png)

Would be glad if someone could point out what error I am making. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your urls.py and the URL you are visiting to get that output?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington urlpattern in urls.py is `urlpatterns = [ path('',views.index,name='index')]`
And I am just visiting localhost at the port 8000

Comment: are you restarting your server so the new code is ran?

Comment: @JimmyPells yes. I might have made it a little muddled in my post, I am trying to clarify -- the code runs as expected every time the server is restarted. However, when the server is running, if I make any changes to the context dictionary, the changes are not reflected in the page when I am reloading it. So for instance if I want to make a minor change, to test it I need to restart the server every time.I was wondering if that is indeed how Django works or am I making an error somewhere

Comment: that is indeed how python applications work, django comes with `./manage.py runserver` for development which automatically restarts the server when your python code changes

Comment: @AnuragChoudhury Are there some errors appearing inside the command, shell or whatever you are using? And to add something to the previous answers: if you have to restart your server with **runserver** every time you are making simple changes to the strings inside your context, there has to be something wrong in my opinion! Sure, sometimes the server crashes and you have to restart it again, but not for such a simple thing as changing strings inside your **views.py**.

Comment: @AnuragChoudhury And before I forgot: I would have saved my templates otherwise, but nonetheless your code is correct and should work as expected.

Comment: @finethen no there are no error messages as well. I am ignoring this issue at the moment because in actual applications, I will not be passing static data, but I will be glad if anyone could help with this regardless. Templates are saved as well

Comment: @finethen I know the issue now, question is how do I fix it -- StatReloader does not work for me and I am not sure how to enable it